# Column family ID mismatch error while persisting data in cassandra in micro-service environment(in lagom)

Tags: cassandra, persistence, microservices, lagom

When I start two different services of lagom, and both the services try to create table in cassandra, I get this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred server side on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found be3ea670-d32f-11e7-8d1b-352a9756e367; expected afea6ff0-d32f-11e7-8d1b-352a9756e367)
```

Even though both the services are creating tables in different keyspaces, still this error is coming. I referred to this answer: [Cassandra 2.1 system schema missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576180/cassandra-2-1-system-schema-missing)

It says that "The cause of this problem is a CREATE TABLE statement collision. Do not generate tables dynamically from multiple clients, even with IF NOT EXISTS." 
But in my case, tables are being created in different keyspace and above all, if I run the services individually, no such error occurs and everything runs fine.

Here is application.conf:

```
cassandra-journal.keyspace = keyspace
cassandra-snapshot-store.keyspace = keyspace
lagom.persistence.read-side.cassandra.keyspace= keyspace
```

Can anyone suggest something???

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `application.conf`'s?

Comment: I have updated the question with application.conf

Comment: Each service should have a separate `application.conf`. If the services have persistent entities, the keyspaces must be unique.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have implemented like this only. Each sevice has its own application.conf and the keyspaces are also unique for each service.